# Facebook add POST to page

Tags: php, facebook, post, feed

I've managed to automattically add a post to my profile using /me/feed/ , but how can I add a post to a page created within my account ?

they say " /[page id]/feed/ " how can I find the right page ID ? Do I need to use another method to post to my facebook page ?

I've searched on how to get the page ID, I've obtained and used this ID: 123397591098452 for page: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Siteique/123397591098452   but the post is not working.

Note: the application has all the right privileges.

This is the way i`m sending the post:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed/','POST',$post);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging into your app under the account the the page belongs to, then turn the code into an oauth token, and then use that oauth token with your request. Good Luck